# Next.js 13 app router middleware for basic auth and i18n

Tags: next.js, middleware, basic-authentication, next.js13

I'm trying to create a middleware function in Next.js 13 to achieve basic auth [using nextjs-basic-auth-middleware](https://github.com/labd/nextjs-basic-auth-middleware/tree/main) and internationalization [using i18next](https://locize.com/blog/next-13-app-dir-i18n/)

If I use the createNextAuthMiddleware function - basic auth works.
But if I use the nextBasicAuthMiddleware it redirects me to /api/auth and gives me 404. In this case basic auth is not working.

My middleware.ts file in the root of the project:

```js
import { nextBasicAuthMiddleware } from "nextjs-basic-auth-middleware";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

const options = {
  users: [{ name: "username", password: "password" }],
}; 

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|assets|favicon.ico|sw.js).*)"],
};

export function middleware(req: any) {
  nextBasicAuthMiddleware(options, req);
  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

Could you please help me understand how middleware works and why the nextBasicAuthMiddleware function works not as expected?
Could you suggest a better approach to achieve basic authentication?

Comment: I create demo project for this issue https://github.com/myrkytyn/nextjs-13-basic-auth